# Form won't submit when action page is changed

Tags: php, html

I have a simple page (below) with a form.  The form will submit if the action='ask.php'.  (ask.php is the current page and the code below).  When i change ask.php to question.php (another page on in the folder) the form does not submit.  Why is this? Is the form redirecting before the data is placed in the database?

ask.php code;

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
       <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <title></title>

      <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap-modal.js'></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

         </head>
          <body>
       <?php include '../css/bar.php'; ?>
    <div id='content'>
<?php include '../nav.php'; 
?>



<?php


if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
include '../connect.php';
$question=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['question']);
$detail=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['detail']);
$date=date("d M Y");
$time=time();
$user=$_SESSION['id'];
$put=mysql_query("INSERT INTO questions VALUES ('','$question','$detail','$date','$time','$user','subject','0')");

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE user='$user' AND time='$time'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

         $q=$row['id'];

        }
}

?>

<form method='POST' action='question.php'>   //won't submit because action is question.php?
    <p>Question:</p>
    <p><input type='text' name='question' id='question'  maxlength='200'></p>
    <p>Add some detail (optional):</p>
    <p><textarea id='detail' name='detail' ></textarea></p>

    <p><input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'></p>
</form>


</div>
<?php include '../footer.php'; ?>
</body>
```

Comment: You can post to any existing page but if that page does not process the posted values, nothing will happen apart from the loading of the other page.

Comment: @jeroen i don't care if question.php doenst process the data, but it isnt even being submitted into the database if i change 'ask.php' to 'question.php'.  why should the action of the form matter if the data gets submitted?  shouldn't it be inputted into the database before redirecting?  if im wrong could you post a solution?

Comment: @jeroen is the problem that the page is being redirected before the data is inserted in the database?

Comment: Submitting to the database = processing. Your php code is run only when the form is submitted to that page. If you submit to another page, the code is only run the first time the page is loaded and nothing is posted yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeroen is right:

The action page should include this kind of information, in order to get the information to the database:

Part one and two make the data ready to be inserted into database:

```
$question = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['question']); // Part 1
$detail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['detail']); // Part 2
$con = mysql_connect("server","username","password");
mysql_select_db("YourDatabase", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO YourTable (question, details) VALUES ('$question','$detail')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
    //Some error handling here,
    // Stay away from using die in all but development
}
mysql_close($con)
```

You should test format with preg_match, too, to check data is in expected format.
Hope that helps

**EDIT!**

This method of connection is outdated!
Use PDO for db connection.
Some docs

[PDO Article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059)

[PDO php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: The only sanitizing necessary when *inserting* to a DB is `mysql_real_escape_string` or `intval`. Anything else, especially stuff only needed for HTML output, should be done after *reading* the data from the DB.

Comment: Didn't realise that, thank you, will correct my post. (I had asserted that you should sanitize w/ strip tags, trim etc, my bad).

Comment: Trim is not a bad idea, but html encoding - more likely `htmlspecialchars` than `strip_tags` - should be done during output as it makes the data worthless for use in a plaintext environment such as text emails.

Comment: Thanks again, ThiefMaster, will apply this logic to my own data handling!:)